# C++ - SQLite3 leaks handles in multithread environment

Tags: c++, sqlite, resource-leak

I wrote a simple program that spawns 10 threads, each thread opens a database (common to all the threads), or creates it (with "Write-Ahead Log" option) if open fails, creates a table on the database and then it goes into an infinite loop in which it adds one row at the time into its table. I found out that the program leaks about 2 handles every 5 minutes, I tried a tool called Memory Verify which tells me that the leaked handles are SQLite3 file locks (line 34034 on the version 3.7.13) but I am not sure whether the bug is in SQLite or in the way I use it.

I haven't specified any compiler option to build SQLite3 so it is built as Multi-Thread and as far as I understand Multi-Thread should work fine in my case as every threads has its own SQLite connection.

To open or create a database I use the following code:

```
   bool Create()
   {
      int iFlags = 0;
      iFlags = iFlags | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_NOMUTEX | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE;
      return sqlite3_open_v2(dbName_sm.c_str(), &pHandle_m, iFlags, 0) == SQLITE_OK;
   }

   bool Open()
   {
      int iFlags = 0;
      iFlags = iFlags | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_NOMUTEX;
      return sqlite3_open_v2(dbName_sm.c_str(), &pHandle_m, iFlags, 0) == SQLITE_OK;
   }
```

The hard loop in every thread calls ExecuteQuery which does prepare, step and finalize of an INSERT statement:

```
   bool ExecuteQuery(const std::string& statement)
   {
      bool res = Prepare(statement);
      if(!res)
      {
         return false;;
      }
      SQLiteStatus status = Step();
      Finalize();
      res = (ESuccess == status || EDatabaseDone == status);
      return res;
   }

   bool Prepare(const std::string& statement)
   {
      return sqlite3_prepare_v2(pHandle_m, statement.c_str(), -1, &pStmt_m, 0) == SQLITE_OK;
   }

   enum SQLiteStatus { ESuccess, EDatabaseDone, EDatabaseTimeout, EDatabaseError };
   SQLiteStatus Step()
   {
      int iRet = sqlite3_step(pStmt_m);
      if (iRet == SQLITE_DONE)
      {
         return EDatabaseDone;
      }
      else if (iRet == SQLITE_BUSY)
      {
         return EDatabaseTimeout;
      }
      else if (iRet != SQLITE_ROW)
      {
         return EDatabaseError;
      }
      return ESuccess;
   }

   bool Finalize()
   {
      int iRet = sqlite3_finalize(pStmt_m);
      pStmt_m = 0;
      return iRet == SQLITE_OK;
   }
```

Do you guys see any mistake in my code or is it a known issue in SQLite? I tried to google it for a couple of days but I couldn't find anything about it.

Thank you very much for your help.

Regards,

Andrea

P.S. I forgot to say that I am running my test on a WinXP 64bit PC, the compiler is VS2010, the application is compiled in 32bit, SQLite version is 3.7.13...

Comment: Consider what happens when all of your threads start up (almost instantaneous) all their calls to open fail, and they all try to create a new db. Start by ensuring that only one thread will be opening and consequently creating a db at a time.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your answer. I created a global mutex and I use it to protect the opening/creation of the database but the hard loop is still leaking handles.

Answer (score -1):

check whether you have sqlite3_reset after every sqlite3_step because this is one case that might causes leaks. after preparing a statement with sqlite3_prepare and executing it with sqlite3_step,you need to always reset it with sqlite3_reset.